# Depth for intersection of prime ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

> Let $R=K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over field $K$.  How can one compute $\operatorname{depth}(R/\bigcap_{i=1}^r p_j)$, where each $p_j$ is generated by some variables $x_i$ and have a same height?

I computed some examples by Macaulay2 but I wanna calculate it manually. I think there exist a general formula for $\operatorname{depth}$ in terms of $\dim R$ and height $p_j$. Can anyone in particular, have gained such a formula? For example, Theorem 2.3 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5646v4) gives a formula but in my question $p_j$'s only have the same height.